# How sorting deals with key and lambda functions in two given lists

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, key

I'm new to programming and learning about the sort function. While I did search and looked at a number of SO articles regarding sort/lambda and some even very similar to my situation, I am still having a hard time grasping how exactly this code works. I also read the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) and the examples there make sense to me but I can't seem to carry this knowledge onto this example here. Would someone be kind enough to help me with the code below? I understand this can be a duplicate but I am only asking because I don't have the knowledge base to get what I've read from other similar posts. Please help if you can, thanks.

```
a = [13, 15, 81, 4]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b.sort(key = lambda x:a[x])
b = [3, 0, 1, 2]
```

How does the order of list 'b' change from [0, 1, 2, 3] to [3, 0, 1, 2]? How does the list 'a' come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Values of the list `b` matter

The values of `b` are of importance as they are used to index into `a`. The example you originally gave does not throw an error because every value of `b` can be used as an index to retrieve values from `b`.

In other words, if the values of `b` changed from `[0, 1, 2, 3]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, this would cause an `IndexError` as the last element, `4`, would be pointing to a fifth element in `a` which does not exist.

---

### Further explanation

`b` is sorted by the function below (a.k.a your original lambda function).

```
def anonymous(x):
    return a[x]
```

What happens under the hood is that every value of `b` is used as an index of `a` to retrieve and compare the values of `a`.

```
a[0] = 13
a[1] = 15
a[2] = 81
a[3] = 4
```

Here, we sort the right hand side of each equation in ascending order: `[4, 13, 15, 81]`. Then, we grab the corresponding values of `b` in the same order: `[3, 0, 1, 2]` which results in the final sorted array `b`.

Answer (score 5):

It sorts `b` as if each element in `b` had the value of the corresponding value in `a`. It might help to see what happens if you sort tuples consisting of each value.

```
>>> sorted(zip(a, b))
[(4, 3), (13, 0), (15, 1), (81, 2)]
```

Notice the second element of each tuple, where they are sorted in the order of their first elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the logic based on your example but could you help me understand what happens little more under the hood?

Comment: There's not too much to say. Functions like `sort` that take a `key` argument apply the function to each element *once*, and uses the result (rather than the element itself) when performing comparisons.